# Why Seaborn could not interpret the inputted column when plotting scatter/lineplot?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to make a visualization of Italy's Covid-19 data.
However, when I tried to use Seaborn's scatterplot in visualizing my data, it couldn't interpret the inputted column even though I had made sure the column is not the dataframe's index.

Below is the screenshot:

[Code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aydOK.png)

Below is the data:

[Italy_data.xlsx Gdrive Drive File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ngWvQwxVL2FfWWm_ADeKAWZBK2Hg5_c8/view?usp=sharing)

So what I want to do is that I want to visualize the rising number of cumulative deaths and cases based on the date/timestamp on the column of "Converted_Date_reported".

Comment: Could we get the CSV / code to work with as text?

Comment: Okay, will add the .xlsx and my description on what i want to do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that the column name contains a space character at the beginning. If you include it, the error will not occur. You should do some data maintenance before that.

```
g = sns.lineplot(x=df['Converted_Date_reported'], y=df[' Cumulative_cases'], data=df)
```

[image]

[image]